# How to loop through a list of words and only keep the ones that have specific letters at specific indexes in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, data-extraction

I have a list of 200,000 words, a list containing indexes, and a keyword. The `index_list` is not predefined and can be of any size between `0 to len(keyword)`.

I wish to iterate through the 200,000 words and only keep the ones that contain the letters in the keyword at the specific index.

Examples:

```
keyword = "BEANS" 
indexList = [0, 3]
```

I want to keep words that contain 'B" at the 0th index and 'N' and the 3rd index.

```
keyword = "BEANS"
indexList = [0, 1, 2]
```

I want to keep words that contain 'B" at the 0th index and 'E' and the 1st index, and 'A' at the 2nd index.

```
keyword = "BEANS"
indexList = []
```

No specific words, return all 200,000 words

At the moment,

I have this code.  `sampleSpace` refers to the list of 200,000 words.

```
extractedList = []
for i in range(len(indexList)):
    for word in sampleSpace:      
        if (word[indexList[i]] == keyword[indexList[i]]):
            extractedList.append(word)
```

However, this code is extracting words that have values at the first index OR values at the second index OR values at the Nth index.

I need words to have ALL of the letters at the specific index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple comprehension with `all`.  Have the comprehension loop over all the words in the big word list, and then use `all` to check all the indices in `indexList`:

```
>>> from wordle_solver import wordle_corpus as corpus
>>> keyword = "BEANS"
>>> indexList = [0, 3]
>>> [word for word in corpus if all(keyword[i] == word[i] for i in indexList)]
['BLAND', 'BRUNT', 'BUNNY', 'BLANK', 'BRINE', 'BLEND', 'BLINK', 'BLUNT', 'BEING', 'BRING', 'BRINY', 'BOUND', 'BLOND', 'BURNT', 'BORNE', 'BRAND', 'BRINK', 'BLIND']
```

Comment: `corpus` is just for demo purposes?

Comment: Yes.  OP didn't include their 200k word list.

Comment: lol jup thought so ;) looked it up

Answer (score 3):

First, change your logic so that your *outer* loop is `for word in sampleSpace`. This is because you want to consider each word at once, and look at all the relevant indices in that word.

Next, look up the [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), which returns `true` if *all* of the elements of `iterable` you gave it are truthy.  How can we apply this here? We want to check if

```
all(
    word[index] == keyword[index] for index in indexList
)
```

So we have:

```
extractedWords = []
for word in sampleSpace:
    if all(word[index] == keyword[index] for index in indexList):
        extractedWords.append(word)
```

Now since this loop is just constructing a list, we can write it as a list comprehension like so:

```
extractedWords = [word 
                    for word in sampleSpace 
                    if all(word[index] == keyword[index] for index in indexList)
                 ]
```

You can handle the case of empty `indexList` separately using an `if` condition before you do any of this.

```
def search_keyword_index(sampleSpace, keyword, indexList)
    if not indexList:
        return sampleSpace # or return sampleSpace[:] if you need to return a copy

    return [word for word in sampleSpace if all(word[index] == keyword[index] for index in indexList)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of (index,character) and use it to quickly compare each word in your list:

```
with open("/usr/share/dict/words") as f:
    words = f.read().upper().split('\n') # 235,887 words

keyword   = "ELEPHANT"
indexList = [0, 3, 5, 7]

letterSet = {(i,keyword[i]) for i in indexList}

for word in words:
    if letterSet.issubset(enumerate(word)):
        print(word)

EGGPLANT
ELEPHANT
ELEPHANTA
ELEPHANTIAC
ELEPHANTIASIC
ELEPHANTIASIS
ELEPHANTIC
ELEPHANTICIDE
ELEPHANTIDAE
ELEPHANTINE
ELEPHANTLIKE
ELEPHANTOID
ELEPHANTOIDAL
ELEPHANTOPUS
ELEPHANTOUS
ELEPHANTRY
EPIPLASTRAL
EPIPLASTRON
```

You could place the result in a list using a comprehension:

```
letterSet = {(i,keyword[i]) for i in indexList}    
eligible  = [word for word in words if letterSet.issubset(enumerate(word))]

print(len(eligible)) # 18
```